# Integrate Podio to send a notification to a HipChat room when a new item is created in an app

Tags: podio, hipchat

I would like to understand how I can send a notification to HipChat when a new record / item is inserted into a Podio app.

I can see that if I pay more money that additional options are made available via the workflows Podio provides utilising Globiflow, but with a large number of users this isn't possible for us.

I have then looked into the Hooks that a Podio app provides, but because this is auto-validated I don't see how I can use this with HipChat.

Does anyone have any experience of this and integrating Podio with HipChat to post a new notification into a HipChat room?

I have used the free trial at Zapier, and got it working, but would ideally like to avoid yet another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podio doesn't provide direct integration with HipChat, so you will have to use something else as communication layer between Podio and HipChat. It could be your own service that will receive webhooks from Podio and post messages to HipChat. Or it could be some other solution that will do something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen so far, Zapier looks like it'll do what I need. Shame I have to pay though for one 'simple' connector task.